# MSE goes up when adding features or more data

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I tried working out a neural network in pytorch and played around a little bit. Essentially, something as easy as trying to predict the value of bitcoin in 5 minutes. I have a couple of various inputs, however I noticed that the moment I started adding features or increase the depth of my NN, the MSE goes down quite a bit. Any ideas why?

```
df.head(2)

X = df.drop('dq', axis=1)
y = df['dq']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

X_train = torch.from_numpy(X_train.values.astype('float32'))
X_test = torch.from_numpy(X_test.values.astype('float32'))
y_train = torch.from_numpy(y_train.values.astype('float32')).reshape(-1, 1)
y_test = torch.from_numpy(y_test.values.astype('float32')).reshape(-1, 1)

device = torch.device('mps')
```

[Output of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fment.png)

Now I'm gonna train it:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(1, 1)  # Linear layer

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.fc(x)
    
model = MyModel()
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience=5, verbose=True)

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())

# Prepare the data
X_train_avg = ((X_train[:, 1:2] + X_train[:, 1:2]) / 2.0)
X_test_avg = ((X_test[:, 1:2] + X_test[:, 1:2]) / 2.0)

model = model.to(device)
X_train_avg = X_train_avg.to(device)
y_train = y_train.to(device)
X_test_avg = X_test_avg.to(device)
y_test = y_test.to(device)

train_data = TensorDataset(X_train_avg, y_train)
test_data = TensorDataset(X_test_avg, y_test)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, pin_memory=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=32)

num_epochs = 40

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0
    total_batches = len(train_loader)
    pbar = tqdm(train_loader)
    for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(pbar):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        total_loss = total_loss + loss.item()
        if (batch_idx + 1) % 100 == 0:
            pbar.set_description(f'Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {total_loss/batch_idx:.4f}')
        if batch_idx == total_batches - 1:
            model.eval()
            with torch.no_grad():
                test_loss = sum(criterion(model(inputs), targets) for inputs, targets in test_loader)
                test_loss /= len(test_loader)
            pbar.set_description(f'Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {total_loss/(1+batch_idx):.4f}, TestLoss: {test_loss:.4f}')
        
    early_stopping(test_loss, model)

    if early_stopping.early_stop:
        print("Early stopping")
        break
```

This is the output:

[The loss is around 2150 in the trainset and 2050 in the testset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vpmi.png)

Then I'm adding features:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(3, 1)  # Linear layer

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.fc(x)
    
model = MyModel()
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience=5, verbose=True)

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())

# Prepare the data
X_train_avg = (X_train[:, 1::4] / 2.0 + X_train[:, 3::4] / 2.0)
X_test_avg = (X_test[:, 1::4] / 2.0 + X_test[:, 3::4] / 2.0)
```

The output loss is already worse:
[The loss is around 100 worse for both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZuAl.png)

Now I added all the features and I made the NN deeper:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_dim, 256),
            nn.ReLU(),
#             nn.Dropout(p=0.05),
            nn.Linear(256, 128),
            nn.ReLU(),
#             nn.Dropout(p=0.05),
            nn.Linear(128, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
#             nn.Dropout(p=0.05),
            nn.Linear(64, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, 32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(32, 16),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(16, 1)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layers(x)

model = MyModel(12)
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience=20, verbose=True)

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())

model = model.to(device)
X_train = X_train.to(device)
y_train = y_train.to(device)
X_test = X_test.to(device)
y_test = y_test.to(device)
```

Now the output loss is around 20k, getting much worse when I add dropouts. I will insert an image soon. Does anyone have an idea what is going on here?

---

**EDIT:** Sandro gave the advice to lower the learning rate. I implemented a CLR algorithm. the losses look a lot more stable. however, losses are the lowest for the most simple model: Any advice?
1 feature + 1 linear activation:
[1 - Linear activation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVppL.png)

3 features + 1 linear activation:
[3 - Linear activation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkRyJ.png)

12 features + Deep Network with Relu Activation:
[DeepNet - 12 features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X992Q.png)

Comment: I updated my answer. I believe the learning rate on 12 features + Deep Network is still too large. Also notice that the best validation loss on 12+NN is better than the best 1+Lin

Answer (score -1):

You did not tune your learning rate. I can tell from the validation loss jumping up and down a lot, so your learning rate is too high. Here is a good method how you can tune the learning rate (eventually you'll be able to do it more intuitively): [link](https://medium.com/deep-learning-hk/some-techniques-in-deep-learning-optimization-1-learning-rate-b4669d5bb568)

Due to Jared's feedback, I'm summarizing the key steps to tuning the learning rate programmatically here:

- Create an array of learning rates value you want to try. They should include orders of magnitudes, e.g. `np.logspace(-9, -1, 21)`
- Loop through the learning rate and train your model for a fixed (low) number of epochs. The choice depends on the calculation time per epoch. In this case, I would recommend something like 2 or 3 epochs.
- Save the validation loss after each run and plot the result.

If you change the architecture or inputs significantly, you should tune the learning rate again.

The result should show that the validation low for very small learning rates and very large learning rates should be bad. If the learning rate is too small, training will take forever and is more likely to end in local minima. For large learning rate, the training becomes divergent, meaning that the updates overshoot the minima and you end up in a bad solution on the other side of the solution space.

To go back to the original question: The problem is still the learning rate, not the selected features. The best validation loss with 1 feature is `2049`, whereas the best loss for all features is `2003`. However, for all features, the minima is already achieved after only 3 epochs and the validation loss jumps around a lot, meaning the learning rate is still too large.

Comment: i tried this and i got a lot more stable validation losses. so thanks a lot for that!

however my training loss still is lowest for the simplest model. the moment I add features or make the network deeper and non-linear for nodes, the loss gets worse. do you have any advice on that?